# Symfony 3.4 application using Guard authentication, how to additional add http basic auth?

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I've got a Symfony 3 application using Guard authentication:-

```
security:
    providers:
        Provider:
            id: AppBundle\Provider\CustomerProvider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout_on_user_change: true
            stateless: false
            logout:
                path: logout
                success_handler: AppBundle\Security\LogoutHandler
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - AppBundle\Security\FormAuthenticator
                provider: Provider


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

As well as providing this Guard authentication I want to wrap the entire site in HTTP BASIC authentication but I can't get both firewalls to work together and seem to get either get no HTTP BASIC authentication or infinite redirect loops when adding an additional firewall required HTTP BASIC authentication.

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    username:
                        password: password
                        roles: 'ROLE_PREVIEW'
        Provider:
            id: AppBundle\Provider\CustomerProvider

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout_on_user_change: true
            stateless: false
            logout:
                path: logout
                success_handler: AppBundle\Security\LogoutHandler
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - AppBundle\Security\FormAuthenticator
                provider: Provider

        everything:
            anonymous: false
            pattern: .*
            http_basic: true
            stateless: true
            form_login: false
            provider: in_memory


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: ROLE_PREVIEW }
        - { path: ^/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

How can I use these 2 authentication methods together?

Comment: as i know, you can only use one auth per firewall. this means in such cases i create my own htpasswd and edit the htaccess file.